# How to fix Animated animations from freezing?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a simple Animated.spring. For some reason doesn't work properly. It starts in the middle of the animation. The image is right here. [https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/b89vcg/does_anyone_know_how_to_fix_this_im_using_a]

```
`upAnim = new Animated.Value(60);


Animated.spring(this.upAnim, {
  toValue: nearbyHeight,
  timing: 500,
  friction: 7
}).start();`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use timing, then use `timing` function with `duration` property. `spring` uses default timing. Here are the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#timing). Make sure to use `useNativeDriver: true` on production so that the animation runs smoothly on a real device and not on the javascript thread which is slower.

```
Animated.timing(this.upAnim, {
  toValue: nearbyHeight,
  duration: 500,
  friction: 7
}).start();
```